# Hector Mapping with out odometry

Tags: slam, navigation, odometry, hector, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using kinect sensor on my custom robot.

I want to achieve mapping with the kinect sensor with out using the odometry.
How can I achieve this..?

Is hector_mapping should be used, if so how can I use this..?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188791/hector-mapping-with-out-odometry/) by [sumanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/18196/sumanth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2014-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See my answer [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/33933/kinect-doing-hector-slam/). Using the Kinect with hector_mapping does not work very well (most of the time) for the reasons stated there.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sumanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/18196/sumanth/) on 2014-08-04**:
I basically need a map from kinect so that I can use the map to the navigation stack.
and get the twist data from the navigation stack for my robot to move around.

**Comment by [Andreluizfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/32882/andreluizfc/) on 2018-01-04**:
@Stefan, is it better to work with the R200 camera and Hector_Mapping? Or should I use the GMapping?